# Cron expression to run every N minutes

Tags: cron

I need to build a cron expression to run a job every 10 minutes after the user click on start button.

I'm trying to do something like:

```
0 42/10 * * * ? *
```

And 42/10 is like the user click to start at hh:42 (example: 18h42). The next schedule is like:

```
1.  Friday, March 20, 2015 6:42 PM
2.  Friday, March 20, 2015 6:52 PM
3.  Friday, March 20, 2015 7:42 PM
4.  Friday, March 20, 2015 7:52 PM
5.  Friday, March 20, 2015 8:42 PM
```

The problem is after second execution, the job waits like a hour to perform the next execution. How can i build a cron expression that starts immediately and after still running after N minutes?

Thank in advance.

Comment: If you really need to start the job at every 10 minutes, after a start time supplied by the user, then you will need to do a calculation and generate the crontab entry accordingly. [Scheduling Tasks with Cron Jobs](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/scheduling-tasks-with-cron-jobs--net-8800). i.e. _You can use multiple numbers separated by commas. This will run three times every hour, at minutes 0, 10 and 20:
0,10,20 * * * * [command]_

Comment: What do you mean with "after the user clicks on start button?"

Answer (score 12):

If you want to run a cron every `n` minutes, there are two cases to consider :

- Every `n`th minute (60 is divisible by `n`)
- Every `n`th minute starting from minute `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:00` (generic)

The latter case is a generic case and covers the case where 60 is not divisible by `n`. It is mentioned that this case needs a "begin-time". With some simple math, you quickly figure why this is.

### Every `n`th minute (60 is divisible by `n`)

For this we use the combination of defining a range and a step value:

> **`man 5 crontab`:** Step values can be used in conjunction with ranges.  Following a range with `/<number>` specifies skips of the
>   number's value through the range.  For example, `0-23/2` can be used
>   in the 'hours' field to specify command execution for every other hour
>   (the alternative in the V7 standard is
>   `0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22`).  Step values are also permitted
>   after an asterisk, so if specifying a job to be run every two hours,
>   you can use `*/2`.

See the following examples:

```
# Example of job definition:
# .----------------- minute (0 - 59)
# |   .------------- hour (0 - 23)
# |   |  .---------- day of month (1 - 31)
# |   |  |  .------- month (1 - 12) OR jan,feb,mar,apr ...
# |   |  |  |  .---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7)
# |   |  |  |  |
# *   *  *  *  *   command to be executed
  m/n *  *  *  *   command1
```

Here, `command1` will be executed every nth minute from m till 59.

This means that :

- if `m<=n`, they will always be spaced by `n` minutes.
  Eg. `m=2,n=10` :: the job will run on minutes `2,12,22,32,42,52`
- if `m>n`, they will always be spaced by `n` minutes, except at the 
  start of the hour.
  Eg. `m=12,n=10` :: the job will run on minutes `12,22,32,42,52`. So here we have a jump of 20 minutes between the `52`nd and `12th` minute.

**note:** you clearly see that if `n` does not divide 60 perfectly, you will have problems. Eg. `m=0,n=11` runs on `0,11,22,33,44,55`, so we only have 5 minutes to the next run and not 11.

### Every `n`th minute starting from minute `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:00`

This case is generic and covers the non-divisibility of 60.

Here it gets more interesting and a different approach needs to be made. This can be resolved when you have a continuous counter from a given day. Enter UNIX time stamp, the total seconds since `1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC`. Let's say we want to start from the moment McFly arrived in Riverdale:

```
% date -d '2015-10-21 07:28:00' +%s 
1445412480
```

For a cronjob to run every `7`th minute after `2015-10-21 07:28:00', the crontab would look like this:

```
# Example of job definition:
# .---------------- minute (0 - 59)
# |  .------------- hour (0 - 23)
# |  |  .---------- day of month (1 - 31)
# |  |  |  .------- month (1 - 12) OR jan,feb,mar,apr ...
# |  |  |  |  .---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7)
# |  |  |  |  |
# *  *  *  *  *   command to be executed
  *  *  *  *  *   mintestcmd "2015-10-21 07:28:00" 7 && command2
```

with `mintestcmd` defined as

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
starttime=$(date -d "$1" "+%s")
# return UTC time
now=$(date "+%s")
# get the amount of minutes
delta=$(( (now - starttime) / 60 ))
# set the modulo
modulo=$2
# do the test
(( delta % modulo == 0))
```

**Remark:** UNIX time is given in UTC. If your cron runs in a different time-zone which is influenced by daylight saving time, it is advisable not to run the command between 2 and 3 o'clock. This could skip the command or run the command twice (depending if the time jumps forward or backwards)

**Remark:** UNIX time is not influenced by leap seconds

**Remark:** `cron` has no sub-second accuracy

Answer (score 7):

I think your format is wrong.  The order of the fields is:

1. Minute
2. Hour
3. Day of Month
4. Month
5. Day of Week
6. Command

So in your example, the `Minute` is 0, and your `Hour` is invalid (`Hour` must be in the range `0-23`).  I'm guessing cron is ignoring the incorrect `Hour`, and running on `Minute 0` of every hour.

However, if you did want to run every *N* minutes, you could use a format like (where *N* is less than 60):

```
0/N * * * * /bin/echo "Your Command Here"
```

However, keep in mind that the `/N` repeats the command every *N* minutes within the current hour.  So, if you have `0/33` in your crontab your command will run at:

- 00:00
- 00:33
- 01:00
- 01:33

Not at:

- 00:00
- 00:33
- 01:06
- 01:39

Comment: 0/N * * * *  is being reported Non-standard! on https://crontab.guru.
Recommended : */N * * * *

Answer (score 4):

I found this [link](https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html), really good: We can get corn expression almost every possible scheduling option:

[image]

Please refer above sample screenshot, its really visual control and self explanatory for to generate any cron expression.

Answer (score 0):

You can't create the cron expression based on the user input or trigger.

Better solution is use a boolean flag to enable or disable the cron i.e. enable the cron service method when user starts the trigger like below:

```
public static boolean cronEnabled = false;

public cronServiceMethod(){
  if(cronEnabled){
     // Keep your logic here
  }
}

// Call this method when user clicks the Start button
public enableCron(){
  cronEnabled = true;
}

public disableCron(){
  cronEnabled = false;
}
```

As far as cron is concerned, make it run every 10 minutes like below:

```
0 0/10 * * * ?
```