# Run a cron job every X minutes, where X is e.g. 50

Tags: cron

I need a cron to run my task every 50 minutes, starting from now exactly.

Suppose it is now 12:10.

So my task must be run at `13:00, 13:50, 14:40, 15:30, 16:20, 17:10, 18:00, ...`

I tried various `crontab` expressions but none of them work;

- `*/50 * * * *`    runs at 12:50, 13:40, ....
- `*/50 13/1 * * *` runs at 13:00, 13:50, 14:00, ....
- `0,50,40,30,20,10/50 * * * *` runs at 12:20, 12:30, 12:40, ....

Any idea how I could express this?

Comment: no, i read this question befor and it is different from my question.

Comment: I rolled back your edit, since it only introduced confusion, and you didn't offer any clarification. Hopefully the title is also now clearer.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49190669/8344060) answer.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no notation in Vixie `cron` to schedule something at intervals which are not an even multiple of something.  You have to resort to the standard practice from before Vixie `cron` (which is only standard on Linux anyway), which is simply to enumerate the times.

```
 0  0,5,10,15,20 * * * yourjob
50  0,5,10,15,20 * * * yourjob
40  1,6,11,16,21 * * * yourjob
30  2,7,12,17,22 * * * yourjob
20  3,8,13,18,23 * * * yourjob
10  4,9,14,19    * * * yourjob
```

For simplicity, this makes the last interval before midnight shorter - only 40 minutes instead of 50 - to avoid having to spell out an even more monstrously complex schedule.

Alternatively, you could run a single `cron` job just before midnight which schedules `at` jobs for the next 24 hours.

```
59 23 * * *    yourschedule
```

where `yourschedule` might be something like

```
#!/bin/bash
for ((i=0; i<60*24; i+=50)); do
    echo yourjob | at $((i/60)):$((i%60))
done
```

Or use a self-scheduling `at` job, which "plants" the next run 50 minutes from now, forever:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "$0" | at "+50 minutes"
# ... your original yourjob script here ...
```

(Not sure your `at` will support that time indicator; consult its `man` page and/or experiment. `atq` shows what jobs you have queued, and `atrm` lets you remove a job.)

In some scenarios, perhaps it's easier to just run `yourjob` every 10 minutes, and have it abort immediately if it's less than 45 minutes since it last ran. (Then you have to make it keep track of when it ran, but it doesn't have to be very involved - probably touch a flag file so its change date indicates the last run.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
if (($(date +%s) - $(stat -c '%Y' .lastrun.50min) < 45*60)); then
    exit 0
fi
touch .lastrun.50min
# ... Your original yourjob script here
```

`stat -c '%Y'` is GNU/Linux; for other platforms, the syntax will be slightly different.)

Before Paul Vixie's `cron` implementation was picked up by Linux and became popular, `crontab` generally didn't permit periodic notations like `*/5`. Back then, you always had to spell out times, like `5,10,15,20,`...

Comment: thanks for your answer. in both your solution, you need to keep track and I can't. (in first solution you need to keep track to get first run time in next 24 hours)

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Keep track of what? The first schedule will start operating immediately; the next run will happen within 50 minutes. If you want it on the next even minute, obviously recalculate the minutes to accommodate that. Then you also risk missing the "now" run if, for example, you run `crontab` on 01:23:59 and the clock rolls past 01:24:00 before `crontab` finishes installing the schedule.

Comment: Suppose you schedule task for 24 hours, and last run time is 23:20, then at 23:59 you want to schedule for next 24 hourse, so your schedule must be start from 00:10:00 , and at next day your schedule must be start from 00:20:00. so you need store last run time of day, to decide about "what is first run time at next day?"

Comment: Then go with the self-scheduling `at` job (third example).